# data entry for master and child on same page in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

Can anyone help me out in telling how to make data entry for master and detail record on same page in salesforce.
the user should not have to move from the master page to child page to fill up the form.

!Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do this.

I have a Visualforce page that saves a main contact, up to 4 related contacts, and a custom object related to the main contact.  I'm going to try and strip the code down to the essentials here because a lot of what I'm doing is saving/copying fields that won't mean anything to others.  Here's the Visualforce code.  Note that we're using the standard controller with a controller extension.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactEntryPageController">
<apex:form id="FastContactEntryForm">       
<apex:pageBlock title="Fast Contact Entry" mode="edit" id="FCEMainBlock" >           
<apex:outputPanel id="InputSec">                      
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact1" id="sc1" columns="2">
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<!-- saveAndBackToEdit is where the related contacts and the child object are saved -->
<apex:commandButton action="{!saveAndBackToEdit}" value="Save" id="theSaveButton1"/><p/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                      
...

<!-- note how we use "inputField" and "contact.FirstName" for fields in the main object -->         
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
First Name:<apex:inputField value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
...   
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Primary Guardian" columns="2">
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<!-- note how we use "inputtext" and "PGFirstName" for related contact and child object fields -->
Primary Guardian First Name:<apex:inputtext value="{!PGFirstName}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Here's the constructor for the controller extension.  The main thing is that you're getting passed the standard controller.

```
public FastContactEntryPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{
...
this.controller = controller;
...
}
```

And here's a code outline for function saveAndBackToEdit where all the work happens.  Notice that we get the current record and make use of the ID from that record when saving the child object.

```
public PageReference saveAndBackToEdit() {
...
//get the main contact being filled out here
ct = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
ct.recordtypeid = '012000000000gKl';  // custom record type  (Salesforce need to be told this)
....
// create child record
Scholar_Program_Application__c sp = new Scholar_Program_Application__c();
sp.Scholar_Name__c = ContactID;
sp.CustomObjectField__c = VFPageFieldForCustomObjectFieldValue;
insert sp;  //save the child object
...
//and finally
PageReference FastContactEditPage = Page.FastContactEntry;  // name of current VF page
FastContactEditPage.setRedirect(true);  //returns us to this page so we can do this again

return FastContactEditPage;
}
```